# Swashbuckle generated Swagger creates duplicate version path in Azure API Management

Tags: azure, swagger, swashbuckle, azure-api-management, openapi

I am trying to configure Azure API Management to use versioning and have it work with a Swagger / Open API document generated by Swashbuckle.

I have an API with 2 versions - 1.0 and 2.0.  I have configured Swashbuckle to generate 2 seperate Swagger documents, one for each version.  All good.

The versioning scheme is by path so consumers need to call the correct path (v1.0 or v2.0).  Like so: https://someurl/v1.0/some/thing

I have defined both versions in Azure API Management and imported both documents.

The problem is that Azure API Management is adding the path to the base URL and then because the path that is defined in the Swashbuckle generated Open API document I'm ending up with https://someurl/v1.0/v1.0/some/thing in Azure API Management.

Below is a snippet of the generated Swagger / Open API...

[image]

And the API version settings in Azure API Management...

[image]

And the full URL in Azure API Management...

[image]

So, my questions is how can I generate a Swagger document, using Swashbuckle or any other tool in a way that I can support Azure API Management versioning using the path versioning scheme.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since OpenAPI specification itself does not allow you to define versioning scheme, it is impossible to infer user intention at APIM level. One may want to import API with /v1.0/ in path as a single API, someone else, like in your case, wants to have API + version set. APIM by default does not create/update version sets during API import, so the only way at the moment is to remove /v1.0 prefixes from OpenAPI spec before you import into APIM.

APIMs domain model allows one to control versioning scheme (path prefix, header name/value, query parameter name/value) at the level of API version set, so that you do not need to duplicate /v1.0 on every operation of your API. By nature of this if your API version set is configured to have path prefix of /v1.0 it will be appended to all API paths included into this version set. And that is what produces the doubling.

Comment: Thanks.  It's a pity that API management doesn't let us check a box or something to tell it that versioning is handled by the API and to not append the version to the backend.